# Custom IAuthenticationFilter and AllowAnonymous in Web API

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, custom-attributes

I would like to make use of `AllowAnonymous` and a custom `AuthenticationFilter`. Can someone point me in the right direction to make use of `AllowAnonymous` or another alternative? Thanks

I've created my own custom filter that inherits from `System.Attribute` and implements `System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter`

```cs
 public class MyCustomAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
```

I have been able to successfully add the logic for the `AuthenticateAsync` method

```cs
 public async Task AuthenticateAsync(
     HttpAuthenticationContext context, 
     CancellationToken cancellationToken) {}
```

My problem is that I need to ignore some of my Web API controller actions or controllers. I thought that I could use `System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymousAttribute` to do this. For example here is a really simple example showing intent.

```cs
[MyCustomAuthentication]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    // no authentication needed allow anonymous 
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("hianonymous")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult Hello(string name) {
        return Ok(new { message = "hello " + name }); 
    }

    // needs to be authenticated 
    [HttpGet] 
    [Route("hiauthenticated")]
    public IHttpActionResult Hello() {
        var name = User.Identity.Name;
        return Ok(new { message = "hello authenticated user " + name });  
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Authenticate()` is still called on `MyCustomAuthenticationAttribute`. I would like to use `AllowAnonymous` or some other method to accomplish this. Thanks for any input.

I know that I can use my custom authentication attribute at the action level and not controller level but there are cases I would like an entire controller or even as a global filter so I need to be able to excluded on an individual action or controller basis.

Comment: For reference I used the example on asp.net site [Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) in getting started on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your implementation of `IAuthenticationFilter` should do **NOTHING** if it does not find an *Authorization* scheme it does not recognize.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

```
// 2. If there are no credentials, do nothing.
if (authorization == null)
{
    return;
}

// 3. If there are credentials but the filter does not recognize the 
//    authentication scheme, do nothing.
if (authorization.Scheme != "Basic")
{
    return;
}
```

The idea is that your filter is simply a way to **AUTHENTICATE** using a known scheme.

You will still need to use the built in `AuthorizeAttribute` and `AllowAnonymousAttribute` to control **AUTHORIZATION**.